# Getting Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) error with WooCommerce PayPal Gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm using the [WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/) and I just noticed that when I load the *checkout* page where the PayPal payment option appears I am getting this in my console:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://www.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger with MIME type
>   text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768
>   for more details.

Is this something that can potentially cause problems or is it nothing much to worry about?

If it is an issue, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Provide the website link

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A full [explanation of CORB is here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md).

To summarize what you have observed:

- The checkout page will load some scripts [e.g. javascript] from PayPal to implement the checkout functionality
- In addition to checkout functionality, it seems that the script may call some PayPal API "logger". From the name, this is likely to be for PayPal's analytics or "business intelligence" purposes.
- Your Web Browser has identified that the response returned from the "logger" API is invalid or inappropriate [according to the CORB logic](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md), and also not relevant to the display or operation of the checkout web page, and so CORB has filtered out the response body/headers.

Filtering out the response body/headers eliminates any opportunity for that response data to have any malicious effect or security risk in your browser (although, in this case there is no malicious intent)

So in summary, it's nothing to worry about. The checkout functionality should not be affected, and PayPal still get their analytics as the "logger" API was still called, just that it's response was discarded.

PayPal could possibly re-engineer the way the "logger" API is used to avoid triggering the message in the browser console, however that may be complex to do with little business value.

Comment: Thank you very much - that's exactly the info I was looking for.